# How to add actors during runtime to group or pool in akka.net when using ConsistentHashmapping?

Tags: c#, routes, akka.net

I want to add and remove actors to a pool (group?) that should receive messages through a router using consistent hash mapping (message has id which is consistent with path of entity).
But after creation of the pool there is only the IActorRef returned and I don't know how to "Tell" about new Actors to add.

I have read several tutorials and hints about routing, for example this: https://github.com/petabridge/akka-bootcamp/tree/master/src/Unit-3/lesson2
but these don't fit.

Maybe I need to write an own router with these messages myself?

Comment: In general adding actors to consistent hash routers at runtime is strongly discouraged, unless you really know what you're doing. As you add/remove actors to consistent hash ring, ranges of hashes, each of existing actors was responsible for, will change. This means that some of the messages that were previously handled by an actor, will now be handled by a different one.

Comment: Why that? If using a group this is just a different way how the message is directed to the handling actor. I could talk to the actor directly or use actor selection (based on identity). The routing is just the strategy with criteria for finding the actor. Could you give an example for such problems? I want to manage a list of entities without being dependent upon message content.

Comment: ... I could use a specific Manager actor which forwards all of the incomming messages to the corresponding IActorRef, based upon Id in dictionary instead of actor selection.

Comment: Consistent hash doesn't route message to actor in one-to-one relationship, but many-to-one. It's common misunderstanding. I've described it in greater detail [here](https://petabridge.com/blog/introduction-to-cluster-sharding-akkadotnet/#why-not-just-use-consistent-hash-cluster-routers-to-distribute-state).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are predefined messages within the Akka.Routing package which allows to add and remove new routees. you can find the code lines in Akka.net [here](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/d86eb6eb4fe512aac603cbc20bddc420acaec74a/src/core/Akka/Routing/RouterMsg.cs). For example the following code adds an IActorRef to an existing router (I tested this with ConsistentHashingGroup):

```
var routee = Routee.FromActorRef(actor);
router.Tell(new AddRoutee(routee));
```

A little bit annoying that I had to crawl through the source code to find the way how to do this because it is not part of petabridge's bootcamp (or did I overlooked it?) and I did't found an answer anywhere else even though I think this is a very typical and common scenario. The documentation is somewhat rudimental in this field.

Hopefully, this helps someone out there to safe some minutes of lifetime and do somewhat more interesting on the domain of the software to develop with Akka.net instead of searching how to use this framework. ;-)